# Why I can't overlay a <Image x:Name="imageListView"> from list view in c# code using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I receive error: `CS0103: The name 'imageListView' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (MaritsaTundzhaForecast)` in c# code when I trying to check the condition from the column in `ListView` and depending on the value of one column to show a different picture in other column.

This is my `MainPage.axml` code:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstLevel">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding dateForecast}"
                                       Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                                 <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding levelForecast}"
                                       Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
                               <Image x:Name="imageListView" />
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

In the c# code I want to use `imageListView.source` but I can't see `imageListView`:

```
 lstLevel.ItemsSource = arg;

            foreach (var item in arg)
            {
                if (item.levelForecast == 1)
                {
                    imageListView.Source = "green.png";
                }

                if (item.levelForecast == 2)
                {
                    imageListView.Source = "yellow.png";
                }

                if (item.levelForecast == 3)
                {
                    imageListView.Source = "orange.png";
                }
                if (item.levelForecast == 4)
                {
                    imageListView.Source = "red.png";
                }
            }
```

I have errors in the `imageListView` ?

[image: Errors on imageListView]

Comment: you can't refer to items in templates by name.  The correct way to solve this problem is to use an IVauleConverter. This allows you convert a property of your model (levelForecast) into a different value (a string containing the value to use as an ImageSource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) that converts `levelForecast` into an `ImageSource`

```
public class LevelToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var level = (int)value;
        string source;

        if (level == 1) source = "green.png";
        if (level == 2) source = "yellow.png";
        if (level == 3) source = "orange.png";
        if (level == 4) source = "red.png";
        
        return ImageSource.FromFile(source);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

then use it in your XAML binding

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <local:LevelToImageConverter x:Key="levelImage" />
</ResourceDictionary>
...

<Image Source="{Binding levelForecast, Converter={StaticResource levelImage}}" />
```

please **read** the docs linked above for a complete explanation of how converters work, I'm not going to repeat every single bit here

Comment: I have error on return ImageSource.FromFile(source); 
Use of unassigned local variable 'source' (CS0165) (MaritsaTundzhaForecast)

Comment: there are the Microsoft docs on that error, they are the very first result returned by Google when searching "CS0165".  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165